# PHPMailer changing Content-transfer-encoding

Tags: php, email, encoding, phpmailer

I'm developing a program which uses PHPMailer.

I want to change "Content-transfer-encoding" in header of email.

Here is my eml format email header sample.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

BUT I want to change "quoted-printable" to "base64"

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Is there any solution change encoding??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [reading the documentation](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#property_Encoding), or looking at the source code. In short, do this:

```
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
```

But I wouldn't advise doing this; base64-encoded HTML bodies make you look like a spammer.

Comment: Oh I solved my problem! Thank you for your reply and documentation link :)

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: @dewd I have updated the link to the current documentation.